# Devise ORM/ODM Adapter for Dynamoid (Rails + DynamoDB + Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, amazon-dynamodb, odm

I'm working on Rails + AWS DynamoDB using Dynamoid gem and it works well. The experience is almost same as Rails + MongoDB using Mongoid gem. The problem is when using Devise in DynamoDB.

For Rails + MongoDB + Devise, I follow this step https://suvankar.svbtle.com/devise-and-mongoid-in-rails-4 and it work nicely.

At first, I though the step is similar and I only need to change the ORM/ODM adapter configuration in Devise. Have checked in https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/lib/devise/orm looks like Devise only support :active_record and :mongoid only.

Should I fork Devise and write orm_adapter for :dynamoid?

Or any clue to make it works for Rails + DynamoDB + Devise in more ease ways?

Comment: There appears to be a solution here, but it is old and may not be maintained: https://github.com/vinaycyadav/dynamoid-devise